# Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type io.realm.RealmList

Tags: kotlin, realm, parceler

My app needs to parcel some objects with realm list attributes. This is the error:

> /StudioProjects/ML/dat-core-android/datcorelibrary/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/release/com/ret/datcorelibrary/model/UserTest.java:29: error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type io.realm.RealmList for com.retoglobal.datingcorelibrary.model.UserTest#photos

Find below the main classes:

**UserTest class**

```
@Parcel(implementations = arrayOf(UserTestRealmProxy::class),
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)

@RealmClass
open class UserTest(

    @PrimaryKey open var id: String = "",
    open var years : Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("profile_photo") open var profilePhoto: ProfilePhoto? = ProfilePhoto("www", "fd"),
    open var location : Property? = null,
    open var town : String? = "",
    open var username : String? = "") : RealmObject()
{

    @ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmUserTestParcelConverter::class)
    open var photos : RealmList<ProfilePhoto>? = null
    set

}

class RealmUserTestParcelConverter : RealmListParcelConverter<ProfilePhoto>() {

    override fun itemFromParcel(parcel: android.os.Parcel?): ProfilePhoto {
        return Parcels.unwrap(parcel?.readParcelable<Parcelable>(ProfilePhoto::class.java.classLoader))

    }

    override fun itemToParcel(item: ProfilePhoto?, parcel: android.os.Parcel?) {
        parcel?.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(ProfilePhoto::class.java, item), 0)
    }


}
```

**ProfilePhoto class**

```
@Parcel(implementations = arrayOf(ProfilePhotoRealmProxy::class),
        value = org.parceler.Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
@RealmClass
open class ProfilePhoto(
        @SerializedName("m") open var photo : String = "",
        open var id : String = "") : RealmObject()
```

**UPDATE**
**RealmListParcelConverter**

```
abstract class RealmListParcelConverter<T:RealmObject> : CollectionParcelConverter<T, RealmList<T>>() {

override fun createCollection(): RealmList<T> {
    return RealmList<T>()
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing code for `RealmListParcelConverter`

Comment: Sorry, updated!!

Comment: Try this approach https://github.com/Commit451/Regalia/blob/3835da4d65509efb462a649c610b6bc9b0560bd8/regalia-parceler/src/main/java/com/commit451/regalia/parceler/RealmListParcelConverter.java

Comment: I'll try and let you know! Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The approach suggested by @EpicPandaForce works. I added the RealmListParcelerConverter from the Github repository and let the `annotation @Parcel(implementations = arrayOf(ProfilePhotoRealmProxy::class))` on the affected class.

Comment: How does your converter looks like? I am trying the same but it always fails with exception: Code generation did not complete successfully